# "Error: Cannot find module '@app/foo'" in prod mode when using libs

Tags: nestjs

I have a project where I built several modules. After finding that nestjs has a lib cli command I ported all of them to use this style.
Now my app can't find these modules when using `npm run start:prod`.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@app/foo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Development/nest-test/dist/src/app.service.js:13:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

I created a project with the basic code and one library to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/hkeio/nestjs-test

Even when I link the package node is not able to find the module.

```
cd libs/foo
npm link
cd ../..
npm link @app/foo
```

When running `NODE_DEBUG=* npm run start:prod` I can see that he is looking at the right place but does not find the module:

````
MODULE 12494: looking for "@app/foo" in [
    "/Users/xxx/Development/nest-test/dist/src/node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/Development/nest-test/dist/node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/Development/nest-test/node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/Development/node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/node_modules",
    "/Users/node_modules",
    "/node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/.node_modules",
    "/Users/xxx/.node_libraries",
    "/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node"
]

...

$ pwd
/Users/xxx/Development/nest-test/node_modules
$ ll @app 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 xxx  staff     96 May 30 09:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  608 xxx  staff  19456 May 30 09:04 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 xxx  staff     65 May 30 09:04 foo -> ../../../../.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/@app/foo```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) of tsconfig-paths it can be used when executing the built sources with node.
The issue comment you are referencing also mentions execution with node.

Actually the problem occurs when executing the built files with node dist/main.js, not during the build process with tsc.

I managed to get a working solution by following [theses instructions](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#bootstraping-with-explicit-params) from tsconfig-paths docs. [@bisonfoutu](https://github.com/bushybuffalo/nest-tsconfig-paths-example) created an example repo [here](https://github.com/bushybuffalo/nest-tsconfig-paths-example).

- Add a file named `tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js` to the root of the project, and paste the code from the docs in it.
- Change the `start:prod` script to: `node -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/main.js`
- You should now be able to compile and execute the project with TS paths. (be aware that you will not be able to compile if there is no path set in `tsconfig.json`)